# Deploy Azure SQL Data Objects Using Terraform using Azure Devops CICD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, devops, cicd

I have deployed Azure SQL Server and Database successfully using Terraform. Now I want to deploy SSDT File (all the objects in the existing database using Terraform.)

I am unable to find .tf code to deploy below Database objects in Repository.

[image: Database File in Repository]

Answer (score 1):

You will not find such resource as this is not the scope of the Terraform. Howeer you can still do workaround and use `null_resource`

```
resource "null_resource" "database-initialization" {

  triggers = {
    filename_sha1 = "${sha1(file("filename.sql"))}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT

        sqlcmd -U $SQL_ADMIN_LOGIN -S ${data.azurerm_sql_server.sql.fqdn} -P $SQL_FOUNDATION_ADMIN_PASSWORD -d ${var.db_name} -i "filename.sql"
        
    EOT
  }
}
```

You can use in similar way sqlpackage to deploy for instance DACPAC. However, what you need to is calculate first hash of the files you want to run and use this as triggers it will cause to triggers resource each time when file is changed.